# Display both parent and child custom taxonomy / content

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display a list of parent and children custom taxonomy and under each the title of any post associated with the taxonomy.

---

What I have now is:

## Category 1

Title

Title

Title

## Category 2

Title

## Category 3

Title

Title

---

What I want is:

## Category 1

### Sub category 1

Title

### Sub category 2

Title

Title

## Category 2

Title

## Category 3

### Sub category 1

Title

### Sub category 1

Title

---

I did some researches but couldn't find a good solution to my problem.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms_customorder( 'publication-type', array(
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'))
);

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'publication',
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'publication-type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                'include_children' => true,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        ),
     );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div id="'.$custom_term->slug.'" class=" pt-100"><h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';
            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="timeline--item-content">
                    <?php if($post->post_status == 'future') echo '<span class="forthcoming"><em>'. __('Forthcoming', 'chairepenale') .'</em></span>'; ?>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="timeline--item-permalink"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
           <?php endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include code of below file so i can give you full code.
get_template_part( 'single-templates/content/content', get_post_type() );

Comment: I've edited to include the content

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the code...It may help you to display layout as you wanted.
>   Also Here I have used ***post type as product*** and ***taxonomy as product_cat***
>   so *you must need to change that as your code*. The layout looks like this http://prntscr.com/mjxvzm

```
<?php
$post_type = 'product';
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'parent' => 0,
));
if(! empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($terms as $term){ $parent_term_id = $term->term_id; $parent_term_slug = $term->slug; ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug,$taxonomy); ?>"><h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2></a></li>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'parent' => $parent_term_id,
                'hide_empty' => true,
            ); 
            $sub_cat_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
                if(! empty($sub_cat_terms) && !is_wp_error($sub_cat_terms)): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($sub_cat_terms as $sub_cat_term){ $sub_cat_term_link = get_term_link( $sub_cat_term ); $child_term_slug = $sub_cat_term->slug; ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $sub_cat_term_link; ?>"><h3><?php echo $sub_cat_term->name; ?></h3></a></li>
                            <?php
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => $post_type,
                                    'post_status' => array('publish'),
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => $child_term_slug,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                 );

                                $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                                if($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a></li>
                                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php } ?> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'post_status' => array('publish'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $parent_term_slug,
                            ),
                        ),
                     );

                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                    if($loop->have_posts()) { ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a></li>
                           <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Well I kind of understand this code, but I'm trying to make it "fit" my structure and it doesn't work at all...

Comment: Let me know what is the problem you have been facing using my code. so I can clear understand.